# Adding protocol layers over socketpair() to get SSL-WebSocket (boost::beast?)

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

I am experimenting with `boost::beast` and WebSockets for a project.  I would like to layer WebSockets (and ideally SSL) onto a `socketpair` (`boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket`).  This seems like it should be easy, but I'm lost in g++ template errors.

**Is there a way to get WebSockets running over an already-connected `generic::stream-protocol::socket`**?

```
int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    io_context                       ioctx;
    local::stream_protocol::socket   socket1( ioctx );
    local::stream_protocol::socket   socket2( ioctx );

    local::connect_pair( socket1, socket2 );

    boost::beast::websocket::???  ws1( socket1 );
    boost::beast::websocket::???  ws2( socket2 );

    cout << "Here we go..." << endl;

    // queue an initial read or write on ws1 or ws2...

    ioctx.run( );

    // all I/O operations completed
}
```